# Como percorrer um dicionário dentro de uma lista em python?

Tags: python, json

Eu tenho o seguinte JSON:

```json
{
    "Aeroportos": [
        {
            "Continente": "Europa",
            "País": "Grécia",
            "Localização": "Atenas",
            "Nome": "Aeroporto Internacional Eleftherios Venizelos - Atenas, Grécia (ATH)",
            "IATA": "ATH"
        },
        {
        "Continente": "Europa",
        "País": "Reino Unido",
        "Localização": "Londres",
        "Nome": "Aeroporto Internacional de Heathrow",
        "IATA": "LHR"
        },
        {
        "Continente": "Europa",
        "País": "Reino Unido",
        "Localização": "Londres",
        "Nome": "Aeroporto Internacional Gatwick",
        "IATA": "LGW"
        },
        {
            "Continente": "Europa",
            "País": "Turquia",
            "Localização": "Istambul",
            "Nome": "Aeroporto Internacional Ataturk - Istambul, Turquia (IST)",
            "IATA": "IST"
        },
        {
            "Continente": "Europa",
            "País": "Croácia",
            "Localização": "Zagreb",
            "Nome": "Aeroporto Internacional Pleso - Zagreb, Croácia (ZAG)",
            "IATA": "ZAG"
        } 
]}
```

E gostaria de olhar em cada "Localização", se encontro uma determinada cidade, tipo "Atenas", e retornar o "Nome", porém não estou conseguindo.

```
import json

with open('iata.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as aeroportos:
    iata = json.load(aeroportos)
```

Essa parte eu consigo acessar o arquivo, tem vários outros aeroportos, daí gostaria de localizar os nomes sabendo que pode ser que retorne mais de 1 aeroporto na mesma cidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fica mais fácil se você entender a [estrutura de um JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) (<sup><sub>e [não é tão difícil assim](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-04-13/como-ler-e-manipular-um-json)</sub></sup>):

1. Você tem um objeto (pois está delimitado por `{ }`), que tem uma única chave chamada "Aeroportos".
2. O valor desta chave é um array, pois está delimitado por `[ ]`
3. Cada elemento deste array é outro objeto (pois estão delimitados por `{ }`)
4. E cada um desses objetos possui a chave "Localização"

Ou seja:

```
{  <-- chaves que abre o objeto principal (item 1 acima)
    "Aeroportos": [ <-- chave "Aeroportos", cujo valor é um array (item 2)
        { <-- primeiro objeto que está dentro do array (item 3)
            "Continente": "Europa",
            "País": "Grécia",
            "Localização": "Atenas",  <-- chave "Localização" do primeiro objeto (item 4)
            "Nome": "Aeroporto Internacional Eleftherios Venizelos - Atenas, Grécia (ATH)",
            "IATA": "ATH"
        },  <-- "}" fecha o primeiro objeto, vírgula separa os elementos do array
        { <-- segundo objeto que está dentro do array (item 3)
            "Continente": "Europa",
            "País": "Reino Unido",
            "Localização": "Londres",  <-- chave "Localização" do segundo objeto (item 4)
            "Nome": "Aeroporto Internacional de Heathrow",
            "IATA": "LHR"
        },  <-- "}" fecha o segundo objeto, vírgula separa os elementos do array
        ...
```

Já o mapeamento de um JSON para objetos do Python é feito de acordo com [esta tabela](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table). Basicamente, objetos são convertidos em dicionários, e arrays em listas.

Então você só precisa pegar a chave "Aeroportos" do objeto principal (cujo valor é uma lista), percorrê-la e ver quais elementos tem o valor da "Localização" que você quer:

```py
import json

with open('iata.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as arquivo:
    iata = json.load(arquivo)
    for aeroporto in iata['Aeroportos']:
        if aeroporto['Localização'] == 'Atenas':
            print(aeroporto['Nome'])
```

`iata['Aeroportos']` obtém a lista de aeroportos. No `for` eu percorro os objetos desta lista, e vejo se a localização do mesmo é "Atenas". Se for, eu imprimo o nome.

---

Se quiser, pode fazer uma função que recebe a lista de aeroportos e retorna os que tem em determinada cidade:

```py
# retorna uma lista contendo os nomes dos aeroportos de determinada cidade
def aeroportos_por_cidade(aeroportos, cidade):
    return [ aeroporto['Nome'] for aeroporto in aeroportos if aeroporto['Localização'] == cidade ]

import json

with open('iata.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as arquivo:
    iata = json.load(arquivo)
    aeroportos = iata['Aeroportos']

print(aeroportos_por_cidade(aeroportos, 'Atenas')) # ['Aeroporto Internacional Eleftherios Venizelos - Atenas, Grécia (ATH)']
print(aeroportos_por_cidade(aeroportos, 'Londres')) # ['Aeroporto Internacional de Heathrow', 'Aeroporto Internacional Gatwick']
```

---

Para a função acima eu usei a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), mas se quiser também pode fazer assim:

```py
def aeroportos_por_cidade(aeroportos, cidade):
    nomes = []
    for aeroporto in aeroportos:
        if aeroporto['Localização'] == cidade:
            nomes.append(aeroporto['Nome'])
    return nomes
```

Comment: ótima explicação. Abraço. +1.